# Building a package in R

Tags: r, package, alias

I'm trying to build a package and it works fine but I get a warning when running `R CMD check my.package` which is

```
* checking Rd metadata ... WARNING
Rd files with duplicated alias 'show,whitetest-method':
'show-methods.Rd' 'whitetest-class.Rd'
```

My package consists of only one function, which is saved in the file `name.R`. However, in this `name.R` file I first need to create a new class (called `whitetest`) and then define the `show` method for it. It is quite simple and looks like this:

```
# Create the new class whitetest
setClass("whitetest", representation("list"))

# Specify the appearance of the output
setMethod("show", "whitetest", function(object) {
text1 <- "White's Test for Heteroskedasticity:"
cat(paste("\n", text1, "\n", sep = ""))
row <- paste(rep("=", nchar(text1)), collapse = "")
cat(row, "\n")
cat("\n")
cat(" No Cross Terms\n")
cat("\n")
cat(" H0: Homoskedasticity\n")
cat(" H1: Heteroskedasticity\n")
cat("\n")
cat(" Test Statistic:\n")
cat("", sprintf("%.4f", object$statistic), "\n")
cat("\n")
cat(" Degrees of Freedom:\n")
cat("", object$degrees, "\n")
cat("\n")
cat(" P-value:\n")
cat("", sprintf("%.4f", object$p.value), "\n")
})
```

I then run the `package.skeleton()` command on this `name.R` file. In my `man` folder the files `show-methods.Rd` and `whitetest-class.Rd` are the ones causing the problem. The `show-methods` file's first lines are:

```
\name{show-methods}
\docType{methods}
\alias{show-methods}
\alias{show,whitetest-method}
```

and the `whitetest-class` file's first lines are:

```
\name{whitetest-class}
\Rdversion{1.1}
\docType{class}
\alias{whitetest-class}
\alias{show,whitetest-method}
```

I get that these things are what's causing the warning, but how on earth do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. The line `\alias{show,whitetest-method}` is in both `show-methods.Rd` and `whitetest-class.Rd`. That's a silly thing to miss and I was going to delete this thread but thought I'd leave it in case someone else would make the same mistake.